# How to perform Parachain Runtime Upgrade via Democracy using Chopsticks

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade

I am trying to perform a `runtime upgrade` using [Acala's Chopsticks](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/tree/master). I used this command:

```
 npx @acala-network/chopsticks@latest xcm -r ./configs/polkadot.yml -p ./configs/my_config.yml
```

I followed the [authorize > enact an upgrade flow](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/upgrade-a-parachain/) for my parachain, and it works.

To produce blocks in local Polkadot, i connected through ws and executed the command:

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "method": "dev_newBlock", "params": [ {"count": 1000} ]}
```

However when I checked `paras` > `futureCodeUpgrades`, I do not see my parachain.
Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what it needed was to produce blocks. Instead of manually performing transactions, I used a websocket command:
`dev_newBlock`

```
{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "method": "dev_newBlock", "params": [ {"count": 50} ]}
```